# Placeholder for input in WYSIWYG

Tags: cms, wysiwyg, placeholder

I've been building a form lately, on a CMS Page. But something strange happens, when I add the following HTLM :

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" name="code" placeholder="My text here"/>
```

and hit "Save" then the page is displayed correctly. However, if I want to add in another edit for that CMS Page, then when showing the code (via the "Show/Hide Editor" button), then my `placeholder` is gone.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that the TinyMCE editor is stripping out your attribute since it thinks it is not valid HTML.

Have a look at Alan Storm's article on the topic: http://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce

Personally, I prefer to just disable TinyMCE completely as it generally causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: Well, that seems really accurate. Thank you.